# What is the proper term for separating code into their own files?

Tags: design, terminology, software

Just curious on how to better explain this with the right terminology. For instance in React, this would kind of be like breaking down a large component into multiple smaller components. But that is specific to React. Is there a software engineering term for just separating out code into separate files? Like having a file just for constants, etc. It's not really quite separation of concerns but more so readability and organization. But just wondering if there is a proper term for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Separating out code into separate files" would cover it.

C calls them "compilation units". Java tries to enforce one class per file. C# encourages this but does not require it. Python calls them "modules". And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know if it were me I would explain it plainly, but I've found it useful to learn the terminology in the event a tech lead throws it out there in conversation.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term I was looking for was decomposition.

Decomposition in computer science, also known as factoring, is breaking a complex problem or system into parts that are easier to conceive, understand, program, and maintain.

Comment: Yes, although that covers a much broader set of activities; you might decompose something into separate *classes*, but depending on the language that may or may not be linked to which disk file it happens to be in.

Comment: Good point ! Yes I guess decomposing is more of a design pattern and not necessarily splitting code into different files

Comment: I would consider decomposition as a logical design concern, rather than a physical design concern (see my answer for the distinction).

Comment: Decomposing allows you to break code out into separate files. It doesn't force you to.

Answer (score 1):

In his classic book *Large-Scale C++ Software Design*, John Lakos introduced the term "physical design" to descibe this aspect: how the source code is split up into individual source files, and what goes where. Physical design, as you rightly note, is an orthogonal issue from "logical design": how classes are related by inheritance and composition, what functionality is provided with each class, etc..

Although the examples in Lakos' book use C++ code, most of the ideas apply to many other object-oriented languages.

Comment: Interesting one, and well sourced!  However, isnt' the [logical vs. physical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68653385/3723423) dying terminology, now that most of the things run on virtual machines and source code repositories replicate the same files and the same changes in many different physical locations?